# Most efficient way to read concatenated json in PySpark?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting one json file where each line in the json is a json itself of 1000 objects, like this:

```
{"id":"test1", "results": [{"property1": "sample1"},{"property2": "sample2"}]}
{"id":"test2", "results": [{"property1": "sample3"},{"property2": "sample4"}]}
```

If I read it as a json using spark.read.json(filepath), I'm getting:

```
+-----+--------------------+
|   id|             results|
+-----+--------------------+
|test1|[{sample1, null},...|
+-----+--------------------+
```

(Which is only the first json in the concatenated json)

While I'm trying to get:

```
+-----+---------+---------+
|id   |property1|property2|
+-----+---------+---------+
|test1|sample1  |sample1  |
|test2|sample3  |sample4  |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

I end up by reading the json as text, and iterate over each row to treat it as json and union each dataframe:

```
df = (spark.read.text(data[self.files]))
dataCollect = df.collect()

i = 0
for row in dataCollect:
    df_row = flatten_json(spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(row)))
    if i == 0:
        df_all = df_row
    else:
        df_all = df_row.unionByName(df_all, allowMissingColumns = True)
    i = i + 1
```

*flatten_json* is a helper that helps me to automatically flatten the json.

I guess there is a better approach, any help would be much appreciate

Comment: spark can read the JSONL file (https://jsonlines.org/). is this failing for you `spark.read.json('yourfile.json')`?

Comment: It works but it doesn't have the expected behaviour

Comment: Please explain what is the expected behavior and what are you currently seeing.

Comment: just edited the post to give you what I'm seeing and what I'm expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON file is called JSON Lines or JSONL which is a supported file format that Pyspark can handle natively. So, use the regular `spark.read.json` to read it and perform the additional transformations to match with what you want.

```
df = spark.read.json('yourfile.json or json/directory')

# Explode the array into structs. This will generate lots of nulls.
df = (df.select('id', F.explode('results').alias('results'))
      .select('id', 'results.*'))

# Group them and aggregate to remove the nulls.
df = (df.groupby('id')
      .agg(*[F.first(x, ignorenulls=True).alias(x) for x in df.columns if x != 'id']))
```

I think this works fine for 1000 lines JSONL, however, if you are curious about alternative solution that doesn't involve generating/removing nulls, please check here: [By using PySpark how to parse nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75061097/by-using-pyspark-how-to-parse-nested-json/75063398#75063398). In some situations, the alternative solution which doesn't do `explode` could be more performant.